# How to set a static date to the from date in the datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, jquery-events

I am working on a date calculator which contain two textboxes with one having a static date like (July 1st 2016) and to date should be changed to the current date.

This code for the to date is working fine but the the static date is not populating itself into the text field.

[image]

Here the from date should be populated. Now the from textbox was given a class name as 'textbox', i have started working on this but it gave me some errors but it does not getting populated.

I have included jQuery for usage before doing this.

```
$('.textbox').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2008,9,03) );
```

It gave me error like this:

> attendance.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function(…)(anonymous function) @ attendance.js:25

I should want like this. Can anyone please help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the jQuery UI library:

```js
$( "#datepickerFrom" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
  });
$( "#datepickerTo" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
  });
$( "#datepickerTo" ).datepicker("setDate", new Date());

$('.textbox').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2016, 6, 1));
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<p>From: <input type="text"  class="textbox" id="datepickerFrom"></p>
<p>From: <input type="text" id="datepickerTo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
$('.textbox').datepicker({"setDate":new Date(2008,9,03)} );
```